# Redeem iCoke Prize Voucher?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Yesterday while in a group with some real ID friends, one of them shared a quest with me which was simply called 'Redeem iCoke Prize Voucher'. When I click on the map icon within the quest to find where to hand this in it always shows me my current location.

[image: Redeem iCoke Prize Voucher]

As you can see, the reward for this quest is a White Murloc Egg companion.

What is this quest and where can I hand in it?

Comment: Well, at least now you'll always know where you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to WoWHead, [this quest is no longer available within the game](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=8026/redeem-icoke-prize-voucher).

[Some discussion on mmo-champion.com](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1128998-Redeem-iCoke-Voucher-Quest-question(s)?p=16748494&viewfull=1#post16748494) suggests that this quest was never intended to be in game and that there is in fact no way to complete the quest.

The [White Murloc Egg](http://www.wowhead.com/item=22780) is actually a Murloc companion named [Terky](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=28487) and there are rumours that he will be made available as a battle pet in Mists of Pandaria.